# Replace spaces with int in a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, replace

I have to replace spaces with `0` (integer 0) in a string. i.e. to null terminate each word in this string.

```
char data[] = "r1 2 3 1.0kohm \n v1 1 0 5.5v";
```

when I do like this:

```
int index = 0;
char token[50];
while (data[index] != '\0')
{
     token[index] = 0;
     index++;                 
}
```

but it replaces with character 0 not integer 0.

Comment: token[index] = 0; will certainly set integer 0, you would have to assign '0' to have character 0.

Comment: I don't understand what you're seeing at all. You're also assigning into a different array, and unconditionally.

Comment: I smell an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you sure you aren't attempting to tokenize the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to replace spaces with 0 (integer 0) in a string.

You can achieve this easily with the [`std::replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) algorithm:

```
std::string data = "r1 2 3 1.0kohm \n v1 1 0 5.5v";
std::replace(data.begin(), data.end(), ' ', '\0');
```

This would also work with a plain `char` array:

```
char data[] = "r1 2 3 1.0kohm \n v1 1 0 5.5v";
std::replace(std::begin(data), std::end(data), ' ', '\0');
```

You will need to include the `<algorithm>` header for `std::replace`.

Comment: isn't this replacing spaces with null characters ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi strange as it seems, I think this is what OP asked for.

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi that would be the same. You cannot insert an integer into a `char` array, but you can place a `char` with value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [@juanchopanza solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902884/231388). But if you don't want to use STL, modify your code to be:

```
const int len = strlen(data);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
     if (data[i] == ' ')
          data[i] = '\0';            
}
```